# css issue in IE7, not sure how to fix

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Go to: http://appointview.com/pricing in Internet Explorer (I am using version 9, but in the dev tools setting it to IE7 mode).

The two divs are not lining up on the top, as they do in higher versions of IE, as well as work fine in FF and Chrome. I have inspected the elements pretty thoroughly and can't figure out what the issue is.

I am not the greatest at cross browser compatibility testing, so maybe there is a fix that is quick and easy?

Comment: Don't ask two different questions with a single post. Post two different question, it's not forbidden.

Comment: There are a lot of known compatibility issues between IE7 and IE8+ design techniques. You will have to design for one or the other. If you think ou will have a lot of IE7 users, then you can force all other IE versions to render in IE7 mode

Comment: on a side note, the worldwide usage of IE7 is only 1.12% as of September 2012, so do you really need to put that much effort into it?

Comment: @AntLaC If it takes me more than 30 minutes to fix, then no, I won't bother.

Comment: Good luck, I've done work at companies where they had users still on IE7 and we had to force all pages to render as if in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 is a mess. Try to remove any white-space between the `div`s, between closing `</div>` and opening `<div>`.

For example, from:

```
  <div>
      First one
  </div>
  <div>
      Second one
  </div>
```

To:

```
  <div>
      First one
  </div><div>
      Second one
  </div>
```

This is a very common bug. White spaces between `inline-block`s is problematic. Try to use mouse to select both div, and you will notice that there is a blank character that occupies the undesired space above the second `div`.